# How to Validate against Entity Framework Core Field Properties with Fluent Validation

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, fluentvalidation

I'm trying to validate against the .HasMaxLength property from Entity Framework Core.

Here is a sample model builder method:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
             {
              modelBuilder.Entity<Address>(entity =>
                 {
              
                  entity.Property(e => e.AddressEmail)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(255)
                .IsUnicode(false)
                .HasDefaultValueSql("('')");
```

Using my context, I can find the maximum length like this:

```
  dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(Address)).FindProperty("AddressEmail").GetMaxLength()
```

Using Fluent Validation, I can do this:

```
  RuleFor(Address => Address.AddressEmail).NotNull().MaximumLength(255);
```

So that works but, when I change the database structure, I have to update my validators.

I'm trying to figure out how to drive my Fluent Validation rules from the entity framework MaxLength property

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**** Partially working way of bringing the dbcontext in but I still am struggling getting the rule:

```
 public AddressValidator(DbContext dbContext)
      {
        Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType et = dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(Address));

        foreach (var Property in et.GetProperties())
        {
            var maxLength = Property.GetMaxLength();
  ---->>>>> RuleFor(x =>x.{PropertyName})    Invalid but this is the idea
        }
```

Comment: Consider to use the Data Annotation validation. In this case you can put some of your property with custom validation to a partial class.

Comment: Thanks, @Sergey - I started using Data Annotation but my validation was too complicated and I kept getting insurmountable errors surrounding the library versions.   It's a good idea - it just won't work for my situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inject your db context into validator using the code you provided before. Not sure if there is an adapter that does it automatically

```
class MyClassValidator : AbstractValidator<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassValidator(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        var maxLength = dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(MyClass))
            .FindProperty(nameof(MyClass.Data)).GetMaxLength();

        RuleFor(x => x.Data)
            .MaximumLength(maxLength.Value);
    }
}
```

**Update**

Version that uses expressions

```
class MyClassValidator : AbstractValidator<MyClass>
{
    public MyClassValidator(MyDbContext dbContext)
    {
        var entityType = dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(MyClass));

        foreach (var property in typeof(MyClass).GetProperties()
            .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string)))
        {
            var maxLength = entityType
                .FindProperty(property.Name)
                .GetMaxLength();

            if (maxLength.HasValue) 
            {
                var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MyClass));
                var memberExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, property.Name);
                var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyClass, string>>(memberExpression, parameter);

                RuleFor(lambdaExpression)
                    .MaximumLength(maxLength.Value);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  It got me much of the way there.   I add to the code in my post with your idea.   The problem is in the RuleFor x.Data I can't insert type type.   I hope you will look at it and let me know of any ideas.  Thanks.

Comment: OMG - Yegor - you are brilliant!   It worked and I’ve been searching for ages about how to do something like that lambda expression.   I will upvote you on your other post since I only have one upvote to give here.