# Constructing A Generic Validator using Fluent Validation and Entity Framework Core - Type Problems in Base Class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, fluentvalidation

I was able to use EF Core properties with Fluent validation to validate maximum field length:

[How to Validate against Entity Framework Core Field Properties with Fluent Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64721374/how-to-validate-against-entity-framework-core-field-properties-with-fluent-valid/64726342#64726342)

I'm trying to extend that by creating a base validation class for all my models.    I'm getting runtime errors instantiating the base class. I'm not sure how to get the base class to know what type class I'm using.

Here is the class I created:

```
 public abstract class BaseValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<T>
{ 
    public object BaseObject {get;set;}
    public BaseValidator()
    {

        DbContext dbContext = new DataContext();

        Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.IEntityType et = dbContext.Model.FindEntityType(typeof(T)); 

        foreach (var fieldProperty in et.GetProperties())
        {
            var maxLength = fieldProperty.GetMaxLength();
          
            if (maxLength.HasValue)
            {

                var parameter = Expression.Parameter(baseObject.GetType());      <<<<<=====  RUNTIME ERROR BaseValidator<T>.BaseObject.get returned null.  
                var memberExpression = Expression.Property(parameter, fieldProperty.Name);
                var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(memberExpression, parameter);
                RuleFor(lambdaExpression)
                    .MaximumLength(maxLength.Value);                
            } 
        }
    }
```

Here is the implementation:

```
 public class AddressValidator : BaseValidator<Address>
{
    public object BaseObject = typeof(Address);

    public AddressValidator()
    {
```

I would so appreciate any help in getting this to work.

Comment: `BaseObject` in `AddressValidator` is not the same as `BaseObject` in `BaseValidator<T>` (you should see a warning on the former: *"Use the new keyword if hiding was intended"*). You're assigning `typeof(Address)` to that (that's suspect in its own right), but the `BaseValidator` constructor is using the `BaseObject` property defined in that class--because that's all it knows--which is *not* assigned. Why isn't `BaseValidator<T>.BaseObject` declared as type `T`?  Why do you have `AddressValidator.BaseObject`?

Comment: @madreflection  Thanks for commenting.  I changed Baseobject to public T BaseObject {get;set;} but how do I set it from my AddressValidator class?  I'm getting the error Temporary local of type 'Address' was null  I think I need to set the type from the constructor  of BaseValidator<T>  but how do you reference it?

Comment: I think you're getting ahead of yourself. Remove `public object BaseObject` from `AddressValidator`. Then in `BaseValidator<T>`, change `baseObject.GetType()` to `typeof(T)`.

Comment: @madreflection - OMG - it worked.  It's the most beautiful thing.   Thank you thank you thank you.  I'd be happy to mark it solved if you put the solution.   I so appreciate it <3

Comment: In addition to the answer, there's one more suggestion I'd like to make. It's not part of the answer because it's not related to the problem at hand and it's more of a matter of style. I've never liked using the `HasValue` and `Value` properties with nullable value types because they're not idiomatic C#. `null` testing and casting are idiomatic, as is pattern matching now that we have that. It might look a little strange at first if you're not accustomed to it, but pattern matching is a good fit here.

Comment: If you do `if (fieldProperty.GetMaxLength() is int maxLength)`, then `maxLength` is just an `int` when you need to use it (i.e. `.MaximumLength(maxLength);`).

Comment: All you need is to replace `MyClass` (ispecific type) with `T` (generic type argument) in the accepted answer implementation from the link. No additional class members are needed. Basically extracting generic class from concrete class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `BaseValidator<T>`, on this line:

```cs
public object BaseObject {get;set;}
```

It declares a `BaseObject` property.  When `AddressValidator` inherits that class and includes this line:

```cs
public object BaseObject = typeof(Address);
```

It declares a *field* that's new to that class and completely different from the property of the same name declared in `BaseValidator<T>`.

You'll find a warning intended to draw your attention to this:

> 'AddressValidator.BaseObject' hides inherited member 'BaseValidator<Address>.BaseObject'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.

You're assigning `typeof(Address)` to that field, but back in the base class, it has no concept of the field or the value assigned to it.  Hiding does not appear to be what was intended so you can remove it.

Now, `BaseValidator<T>.BaseObject` is the only one you have left (and the only one the constructor ever saw).  However, it was never assigned a value, so when the constructor tried to get its value, it could only be `null`.  That, of course, means you were getting `NullReferenceException`.

Based on the expression you're building, you want the parameter to be the entity type, which you have conveniently in the type argument, `T`.  Use `typeof(T)` there instead:

```cs
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
```

That will create a parameter expression of the entity type `Address` specified when `AddressValidator` derives from `BaseBalidator<Address>`.

It looks like you want `BaseObject` to be the object to be validated.  Declare it as type `T`.

```cs
public T BaseObject { get; set; }
```

To assign it in the base class, accept it in `AddressValidator`'s constructor and pass it through to the base class's constructor.

```cs
public class AddressValidator : BaseValidator<Address>
{
    public AddressValidator(Address baseObject)
        : base(baseObject)
    {
    }
}

public abstract class BaseValidator<T> : AbstractValidator<T>
{
    public BaseValidator(T baseObject)
    {
        BaseObject = baseObject ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(baseObject));

        //... and then the rest of the constructor as you have it.
    }
}
```

Since the constructor is assigning `BaseObject` and you probably don't need it to change, you can make it a read-only property:

```cs
public T BaseObject { get; }
```

Comment: Thank you!   You are awesome!!